# What can be wrong with this gradle build? "What went wrong: Index: 0, Size: 0"

Tags: gradle, build

I am using [gradle 3.1](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v3.1.0/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/execution/taskgraph/DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java) and for

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

I get the following output. What does this mean? Have you ever seen this error?

> Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Index: 0, Size: 0
> - Try:
>     Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is:
>     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.onOrderingCycle(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:404)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.determineExecutionPlan(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:286)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.ensurePopulated(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:202)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:109)
>     at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:186)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:183)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:33)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
>     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:79)
>     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:59)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:44)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:293)
>     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.815 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly an instance of [GRADLE-3575](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3575).
Can you try with Gradle 3.2?